# Arcpy get spatial reference problem

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to obtain the spatial reference for lists of feature classes using the following code;

```
def spatialFileListing():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputLocation):
        for d in dirs:
            workspace = os.path.join(root, d)
            arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
            fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
            for fc in fcList:
                fcPath = os.path.join(workspace, fc)
                desc = arcpy.Describe(fcPath)
                descSR = desc.SpatialReference.Name
                print(descSR)
```

The below error message is returned;

"AttributeError: DescribeData: Method SpatialReference does not exist".

However, when I substitute for a fixed path to a shapefile e.g.:

fcPath = r"C:\Fixed\Path\To\Shapefile\A_Shapefile.shp"

The spatial reference is returned. E.g.:

"ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_31N"

I'm sure it is something to do with the name / structure of the feature class being returned within the for loop, but don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: At the moment you are presenting a copy/paste from your code rather than a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) but, in any event I think you should `print(fcPath)` before you try to Describe it so that you are certain which data item is throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that and find out what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `dirs`, `root` will give you correct path:

```
def spatialFileListing():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputLocation):
        workspace = root
        arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for fc in fcList:
            fcPath = os.path.join(workspace, fc)
            desc = arcpy.Describe(fcPath)
            try:
                descSR = desc.SpatialReference.Name
                print(descSR)
            except AttributeError:
                print('Failed on fc: ',fc)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This returns one spatial reference then fails with the same error message; "AttributeError: DescribeData: Method SpatialReference does not exist".

Comment: def main():
        spatialFileListing()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

Comment: Maybe you have feature classes without spatial reference. Add a print statement after `for fc in fcList` and check that feature class

Comment: If that is the case, I would need some code to deal with that situation wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes I've been trying to find a describe propetry like "desc.hasSpatialReference" but i cant find one. You can use try/except

Comment: Of course. Capture the fact there is not a spatial reference and then move on to the next feature class. Thanks. I can deal with that. It's a case of working out how best to capture and then move on using something like "continue" or "break". Thanks. I'll work it out and post the code that works.

Comment: Im not sure if describe will cause AttributeError if the fc does not have a spatial reference, you should make sure so you dont try/except away some other error.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works. I realise I still need to include a try: except statement to catch anything untoward.

```
def spatialFileListing():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputLocation):
        workspace = root
        arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for fc in fcList:
            spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference
            if spatial_ref.name == "Unknown":
                print("{0} has an unknown spatial reference".format(fc))
            else:
                print("{0} : {1}".format(fc, spatial_ref.name))
```